# Appending to array yields "Cannot index into a null array"

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I would like to append data collected from a foreach loop to an array which was declared outside/prior of the loop.  However, I am receiving a "Cannot index into a null array" error, and I don't understand why the array is 'null' if I've declared it already?

```
function execute_file {
    $file_output = Read-Host "Enter the .CSV local location where you would like to save resultant output.  For example, 'G:\documents\output.csv'"
    $vm_list = Get-VM | Sort-Object Name
    $AllObjects = @()

    foreach ($vm in $vm_list) {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $vm ..."
        $AllObjects += [pscustomobject]@{
            Name                     = $vm
            "IP Address"             = (Get-VM -Name $vm).guest.IPAddress[0]
            "Guest OS"               = (Get-VM -Name $vm).Guest.OSFullName
            PowerState               = (Get-VM -Name $vm).PowerState
        } | 
        Export-Csv -Path $file_output -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

The error I receive, but don't understand, is below:

```
Line |
  51 |          $AllObjects += [pscustomobject]@{
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot index into a null array.
```

Comment: The line throwing the error is this one `(Get-VM -Name $vm).guest.IPAddress[0]`. Change it to `(Get-VM -Name $vm).guest.IPAddress | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Also, not sure why the need to query `$vm` 3 times (`Get-VM -Name $vm`) ?

Comment: btw. you already have that information in ```$vm``` no need to run get-vm for each setting, just replace ```get-vm -name $vm``` with ```$vm```

Comment: .Net expression is very picky about empty objects. I agree on the `| Select` solution instead.